# How I can convert nnetar model in to a data frame?

Tags: r, neural-network, time-series, fortify

Hello and thanks for reading me. I am working with a neural network model and I am trying to convert this to a data frame using fortify, but I realize that neural network models are not supported by fortify and I don't know how I can transform this model :(

Anyone knows how I can do this?

The code I used (to get an idea of what I want to do) is as follows:

```
library(ggfortify)
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)

model <- forecast(h = 24, nnetar(P = 2, p =1,AirPassengers))
fortify(model)
```

Comment: The output from `forecast` is a list with 16 elements. Which of those do you want to convert to a data frame?

Comment: `as.data.frame(model)` may do what you want.